# Selenium does not recognize the CSS path for a second element on the page

Tags: css, xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to use a CSS selector to click on a link in Selenium but it fails to recognize it.

The link called "Cancel" appears in two places in the page.

The xpath for the first Cancel link is:
`//html/body/div[@id='c_account']/div[@id='a_returns']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='main_col']/div/div[@id='create-return']/div[1]/div/a[2]/span`

The xpath for the second link is:
`/html/body/div[@id='c_account']/div[@id='a_returns']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='main_col']/div/div[@id='create-return']/div[4]/div/a[2]/span`

When I inspect both links in Firebug I get the same CSS path.
`html body.p div#c_account.c_wrapper div#a_returns.a_wrapper div#container div#main div#main_col div.main_content div#create-return div.return-process-actions div.return-process-action-buttons a.return-process-cancel`

And when I use Selenium to click on the second link it clicks the first because the css path is the same for both.

**Is there a way to distinguish between the two links through css path?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the x:nth-child(n)

Look up this site: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/ ... what you need is #22

Also, you really might not need such a long css selector, you can just use

```
a.return-process-cancel:nth-child(1)  
a.return-process-cancel:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off in the long run adding an `id` with a meaningful name to the links you want to click.  Your test will be much easier to read later when you have lines like

```
selenium.click("firstCancelLink");
```

than

```
selenium.click("css=html body.p div#c_account.c_wrapper div#a_returns.a_wrapper div#container div#main div#main_col div.main_content div#create-return div.return-process-actions div.return-process-action-buttons a.return-process-cancel");
```

Comment: true, but thats not the solution i'm looking for as I can't change the code that was written by the developer.